# Post Name Permalink setup gives 404 error inside sub-directory

Tags: permalinks

I have setup my first AWS EC2 account and installed nginx. The root is `/usr/share/nginx/html`. I have installed `WordPress` as a sub-folder called cooking under root. the site address is http://54.226.50.133/cooking.

As long as I have permalink setup as Plain, pages are coming up ok, but when I update permalink structure to use Post Name, I get 404 error.

http://54.226.50.133/cooking/?p=1 - runs OK
http://54.226.50.133/cooking/hello-world/ - gives 404

**Location of WordPress installation (cooking):** `/usr/share/nginx/html/cooking`
**Location of `.htaccess` file:** `/usr/share/nginx/html/cooking/.htaccess`
**Content of `.htaccess` file:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I am not sure but multisite might be a solution but I don't want to go this far right now, rather I want to keep it simple at the beginning. Basically I will need more sub-folders (different WP installations for different sites) like this under `usr/share/nginx/html` folder for demonstration purpose.

Please suggest me the right way to achieve this.

**UPDATE**
I have Permalink setting set to **Post Name** for the moment, so http://54.226.50.133/cooking/?p=1 will give 404 right now, which is OK. But http://54.226.50.133/cooking/hello-world/ still ends up with 404.

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: htaccess files only work on Apache servers, they'll do nothing for nginx servers. You'll need to modify nginx configs instead

Comment: Yes, after some research I have come to know that nginx has no connection with .htaccess! I am trying to set things up for nginx. @Hasin Hyder is trying to help me out!

Comment: proptip: steal the nginx configs from VVV, take special note of https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/blob/develop/config/nginx-config/nginx-wp-common.conf

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because Nginx doesn't interpret rewrite rules like Apache via mod_rewrite. You need to change your nginx vhost config file (nginx site config file, i.e /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-site-config.conf file)

Add the following line inside server block

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
}
```

if the `location /` is already present, then remove the existing try_files directive and replace it with the following line

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

Now restart or reload Nginx and your problem will be gone. Here is a good article link regarding this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-nginx-for-wordpress-permalinks/

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. the problem is I don't have the folder `sites-enabled` under `/etc/nginx`!! What should I do? :(

Comment: ok what do you have there?

Comment: Under `/etc/nginx` I have `conf.d (folder), fastcgi_params, mime.types, scgi_params, win-utf, default.d (folder),  fastcgi_params.default, mime.types.default, scgi_params.default, fastcgi.conf, koi-utf, nginx.conf, uwsgi_params, .conf.default, koi-win, nginx.conf.default, uwsgi_params.default`. Under `conf.d`, two files: `default.conf` and `virtual.conf`. There is nothing under `default.d` folder.

Comment: It's inside conf.d folder - look for the conf file that has a text line "server_name" which matches to your site address, change only that file

Comment: Adding server name 54.226.50.133 or 54.226.50.133/cooking gives "No input file specified." when I am running http://54.226.50.133/cooking. I added a screenshot in original post.

Comment: Remove that try_files $uri $uri/ =404 /index.php?$args; and add try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

Comment: After reloading Nginx, save your permalink (from WordPress admin panel again)

Comment: I did exactly what you said but still no luck! Getting the same error :(